# Linear Regression problem, ridiculously high loss

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csv = 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Downloads\\weight-height.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(csv)
df.head

x_train = df['Height'].values
#into centimetres because im english
x_train = x_train * 2.54
y_train = df['Weight'].values
#into kilos because im english
y_train = y_train / 2.2046226218

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, c=None)
plt.show()
print(X[:10])
print(y[:10])

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
import numpy as np

X = np.array(x_train).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array(y_train).reshape(-1,1)

X = X[:5000]
y = y[:5000]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(36, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(18))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X,y, batch_size=1, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1)

#plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
#plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
```

My problem is pretty much that I'm a noob and I'm trying to create my own linear regression model from scratch using keras and I can't understand why my loss is so high. I need to know if its the optimizer or loss function I'm using or a data problem. The dataset is simply a list of weights and heights.

Comment: I suggest trying to fit a straight line to two data points - that should be much simpler to troubleshoot, especially if you know the correct answer in advance.

Comment: You are training for a single epoch, with batches of a single sample, that is a big problem. You should train for longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

1. Normalising your heights and weights so that the maximum of each is one. Deep learning is generally easier when values are about one. Obviously you need to do the same division to your test data, and then multiply the answers by the same amount at the end.
2. Changing your metric to 'mse' or 'mae' (mean squared error or mean abs error). This won't change your loss, but will make you feel better as it is a more meaningful measure of how well you are doing.

Try this:

```
x_train = df['Height'].values
x_train = x_train * 2.54
x_train = x_train / 175.0

y_train = df['Weight'].values
y_train = y_train / 2.2046226218
y_train = y_train / 80.0
```

...

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='mean_squared_error',
          metrics=['mse'])
```

And to test some new values

```
x_test = 187
x_test = np.array(x_test).reshape(-1,1)
x_test = x_test * 2.54
x_test = x_test / 175.0
pred = model.predict(x_test)
pred = pred * 80.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much, so why do you divide height by 175 and divide weight by eighty, everything else makes sense now though, could I not use a sigmoid curve instead?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that. I chose 175 cm and 80 kg as reasonable values that are roughly in the upper end of a distribution of human heights and weights. I chose 187 in the test because that's my height!
You could use a sigmoid as the activation for your hidden units, but your output unit needs to be able to output values greater than one, in case your test height is greater than any of the training heights.
Why normalise inputs? Watch this: https://www.coursera.org/lecture/deep-neural-network/normalizing-inputs-lXv6U

Comment: Thanks so much, its really useful to learn this stuff through people teaching me, thanks